# Adding Quotation marks around string with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-processing

I have a text file to process, with huge number of lines like this:

> 000AA Sylvester Stallone
>
> 000AD Demi Moore

I would add for each word, a single quotation mark like this:

> '000AA' 'Sylvester' 'Stallone'
>
> '000AD' 'Demi' 'Moore'

I suppose that the best(and maybe the  only way?) is to use notepadd++ find/replace with regex, but unluckily I have not enough knowledge. Please, there is someone can help me? This will be a huge time saver help!!

Comment: Are there any other lines you do not want to touch? If yes, what makes the ones you want to modify specific (and thus we could match them with  some pattern)? Did you try anything at all? Do you know how to use a regex-based search and replace in Notepad++? I ask because if I say *use `\S+` and replace with `'$0'`*, is that enough?

Answer (score 13):

Just search for

```
([^\s]+)
```

(Matches every character but any whitespace)

and replace it with

```
'$1'
```

(replaces the match with the same string, but leading and trailing `'`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm!! just another little question can I add  open/close parenthesis at the start/end of each line with regex? like this:

from '000AA' 'Sylvester' 'Stallone' to ('000AA' 'Sylvester' 'Stallone')

ps. in one regex would be the perfection :)

Comment: Replace first character with itself followed by opening bracket: search: `^(.)`, replace: `\($1` - Replace last character with itself followed by closing bracket: `(.)$` -> `$1\)`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the last regex.could you explain me better? I must replace the old regex or add this last one? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's Independent regex'. You have to run three: First, add quotes, second add opening bracket, third add closing bracket. (last one means: search `(.)$`, replace: `$1\)`

Comment: well actually the last two can be merged: search `^(.*)$`, replace: `\($1\)`

Comment: May I add a critique that your capture group could be simplified with `(\S+)`?

Comment: @Erutan409 You are right, but out of a personal flavor I never use the capital letters along with regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, you saved me hundreds of works' hour